# JDBC Bath - ERROR Batch entry 295 <unknown> was aborted: Возвращено слишком много результатов обновления. В чем проблема?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Есть много одинаковых запросов insert, и для ускорения выполнения этих процессов, я хочу использовать statement.executeBatch();

вот часть кода:

```
public void executeRequest() {
    try {
        statement.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();
    } catch ( SQLException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void addBatch(String request){
    try {
        statement.addBatch(request);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        log.error("\n\n"+request);
    }
}
```

Но в результате получаю ошибку:

2018-11-06 10:13:49 ERROR SettingDataBase:39 - Batch entry 295  was aborted: Возвращено слишком много результатов обновления.  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.

На сколько я знаю, batch ограничен только размером памяти. 
В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Пример записи в batch:

```
INSERT INTO "C_Parameters" ("DefaultValue", "DeletionMark", "Ref", "Description", "ValueType", "Code")
VALUES ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Value><Type>Catalog.дом</Type><Data>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Data></Value>', 'false', '15a4242d-adf9-4cef-8e40-ce1d64e2dde2', 'Обслуговує агент', 'eJxdUL0KwoDCGNzjw==', '000000023')
ON CONFLICT ("Ref") DO UPDATE SET
"DefaultValue" = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Value><Type>Catalog.дам</Type><Data>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Data></Value>',
"DeletionMark" = 'false',
"Ref" = '14a3242d-adf4-4cef-8e40-ce4d64e2dde2',
"Description" = 'Тест',
"ValueType" = 'eJxdUL0KwjAQ3n2KKBNd6pxL==',
"Code" = '000000023';
```

Comment: Покажите сами бэтчи

Comment: добавил в описание. Через execute все работает нормально

Answer (score 0):

C `Batch` все таки обычно работают по другому, а именно:

1. Создаем `PreparedStatement`
2. В цикле задаем параметры `PreparedStatement` и добавляем `addBatch()`
3. Выполняем `executeBatch()`

Примерно так:

```
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    String compiledQuery = "INSERT INTO TESTDB.EMPLOYEE(EMPNO, EMPNM, DEPT, RANK, USERNAME)" +
            " VALUES" + "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(compiledQuery);

    for(int index = 1; index <= records; index++) {
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, index);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "empo number-"+index);
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, index+100);
        preparedStatement.setInt(4, index+200);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, "usernames");
        preparedStatement.addBatch();
    }
    int[] inserted = preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

Comment: там достаточно сложная процедура формирования запросов.  PreparedStatement не подходит.